# GSAP after clear timeline reverse animation not working

Tags: gsap

I am facing an issue when I clear the timeline using `timeline.clear()` to move back all the elements to it's original position because of `immediateRenderer = true`, now issue I am facing is after clear timeline revert is not working.

Please suggest a proper solution that includes immediateRenderer to true with on complete of animation elements should reset to it's original position and revert should work after clear the timeline

I have also search into GSAP forum but not get any proper solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you clear() a timeline, that literally deletes all of its child animations, so it'd make sense that if you try to revert by doing something like seek(0), it would have no effect (there are no child tweens to re-render at their staring values). It sounds like maybe you just shouldn't call clear() before reverting.

If your goal is to revert the changes that a tween or timeline made, you should be able to simply seek(0) to jump back to the starting time, and if you want to pause it there so that it doesn't continue playing just pause(0) like:

```
var tl = new TimelineLite();
tl.to(...);
//then later...
tl.pause(0);
```

Is that what you're looking for?

If not, it'd be super helpful if you could provide a reduced test case in codepen or jsfiddle so that we can see what's going on.

Also, were you saying that you posted in the GreenSock forums but you didn't receive an answer? We're usually very good about answering every question, typically in less than 24 hours. Let me know if there's something we missed.

Comment: I have tried using seek(0) and also with pause(0) but elements are not reset to it's original position.. that's the issue actually I am facing right now

Comment: Do you have a codepen demo? Did you already post in the GreenSock forums? I'd love to help - it's just difficult to troubleshoot blind.